# Why does "Zeichen von" lose the preposition when its complement is a sentence?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

When a preposition is followed by a sentence, then add **da-**. However

**ein Zeichen von Diabetes** becomes
**ein Zeichen dass er Diabetes hat**

without **davon**. What is special about **Zeichen** and what are other such special cases?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ein Zeichen von Diabetes
>
> ein Zeichen der Diabetes
>
> ein Zeichen (davon), dass er Diabetes hat

The *davon* is optional, it's actually good style not to use it here. That is because genitive attributes are preferred over *von*-objects in German, and this extends to object clauses that replace them, too.

So this is a feature of *von*. Or better, a way to avoid the *von*.

> Man sieht es am anderen Verhalten der anderen Präpositionen.
>
> Man sieht es daran, dass die anderen Präpositionen sich anders verhalten.

Comment: Please elaborate on ""genitive attributes are preferred over von-objects". In which situations? Is "von" frowned at these  constructions?

Comment: The preposition *von* marks the origin of something. This can be used in the sense of a place, and in a transferred sense. This latter use is 100% covered by genitive attributes already and they should be used instead. In sentences with many genitives, *von* is used instead of a genitive to denote the owner: *Dies ist ein Zeichen der Diabetes des Patienten von Dr. Boess.*